Multiple conditions but should return only 1 record with the most restrictive condition
Suppose I have these records in a table sems
Id | semcode | degreeID | programID | sessionid
1  | 2023.1  | CERT     | NULL      | NULL
2  | 2023.3  | UGD      | BEDS      | NULL
3  | 2023.2  | UGD      | NULL      | SE01
4  | 2022.5  | UGD      | NULL      | NULL
5  | 2021.2  | DIPL     | DTHE      | NULL
6  | 2025.0  | PHD      | NULL      | NULL

I want to just select 1 record (semcode) with these conditions
-> If DegreeID is null, all degree types should use the semcode
-> If degreeID has value, but programID is null and sessionid is null, degree type with the value irrespective of particular program or particular session should use the semcode
-> If degreeID has value, programID has value and sessionid is null, degree type with the value and program with value but any session should use the semcode
-> If degreeID has value, programID has value and sessionid has value, degree type with the value and program with value and session with value should use the semcode

What I have done, I believe is not getting me accurate results I want so far
Declare @degID varchar(10) = 'UGD', @progID varchar(10) = 'BEDS', @sesID varchar(10) = 'SE01'
Select Top 1 semcode from(
Select semcode from sems where degreeID = @degID and programID = @progID And sessionID = @sesID union
Select semcode from sems Where degreeID = @degID AND (programID = @progID OR sessionID = @sesID) union
select semcode from sems Where DegreeID = @degID union
select semcode from sems where degreeid is null and programid is null and sessionid is null
) tab

Expected results with these parameters
@degID = 'UGD', @progID = 'BEDS', @sesID = 'SE02' must return '2023.3'
@degID = 'UGD', @progID = 'BEDA', @sesID = 'SE01' must return '2023.2'
@degID = 'DIPL',@progID = 'BEDS', @sesID = 'SE02' must return NULL
@degID = 'PHD', @progID = 'MPH', @sesID = 'SE01' must return '2025.0'
@degID = 'CERT', @progID = 'DTHE', @sesID = 'SE01' must return '2023.1'

The parameters are never null or blank
Any pointers?

Please firstly indicate which row is the correct result for the sample data. And also clarify what you mean by for example If DegreeID is null, all degree types should use the semcode where does a degree type come into it?

While I don't follow your logic, the solution is to put the conditions in your order by clause, most restrictive first, I don't think you need to union them.

added expected results to give it some perspective

Can you whip up a https://dbfiddle.uk/ - I can't be asked to type the data in myself

If you stick to the union approach, might want to consider using a UNION ALL instead

Fab, that would just allow the same row to show up more than once, one time from each select, no?

I strongly suggest adding an explanation to each desired result. No matter how I read your explanation, data, code and desired results, something always doesn't make sense to me. Adding a concrete description to each will help immensely. (Also, you give no examples where the any of the parameters are NULL, yet you have a NULL in the code example.)

Nice work, but your result set is not ordered by the order of the union'd selects in the select statement.
You must add a column with an order, and order by it!
Select top 1 semcode from (
       select 1 as order, semcode where ...
 Union select 2 as order, semcode where ...
 Union select 3 as order, semcode where ...
 Union select 4 as order, semcode where ...
 Order by order);

Note that this will be a bit inefficient, because you have to do four queries. With judicious use of coalesce you might improve that.
Alternatively, we can use coalesce to match on either the parameter or null, and, as mentioned in the comments, use the order by clause to rank by calculating a "score". Since we've given better matches better scores, we order by desc:
Select top 1 semcode from sems 
where     
       coalesce(degreeID, @degID) = @degID 
   and (@progId is null or coalesce(programID, @progID) = @progID)
   And coalesce(sessionID, @sesID) = @sesID 
Order by 
    Case when degreeID = @degId then 8 else 0 end 
  + Case when programID = @progId then 4 else 0 end 
  + Case when sessionId = @sesId then 2 else 0 end 
  Desc

Note that we allow @progID to be null and ignore it if it is, but we don't need to do this for the other two parameters, because you gave them default values.
That's a single query (the OR is on a parameter, so it won't force a separate query) so it's possibly more efficient, depending on your rdbms. We could replace
coalesce(degreeID, @degID) = @degID 

with
(degreeID is null or degreeID = @degID)

to be more explicit at the cost of more verbosity. For some rdbmses, coalesce might prevent index use.
If we're using MySQL (5.7), which is notorious for silently doing "helpful" type conversions, we can instead:
order by 
    (degreeID = @degId)   * 8
  + (programID = @progId) * 4
  + (sessionId = @sesId)  * 2
Desc 

But using case is more portable.
Also, I did this on my phone without running it against any db, so test it.

In SQL there is no such thing as a case statement it is a case expression - incorrect naming is the cause of many newbies to SQL using it incorrectly. Please check the documentation and revise - as I tried to help you do, but for some reason you chose to revert it.

Thanks DaleK, I'll review the documentation and update my answer after I've done so. Thank your for your concern! I just noticed that I've visited  stackoverflow 1337 days, isn't that funny!

"Note that this will be a bit inefficient, because you have to do four queries" it's probably more efficient than the single query, because it can use Merge Concatenation and therefore only query a single table https://sqlperformance.com/2014/09/t-sql-queries/avoiding-sorts-merge-join-concatenation

Naming a column order is a bad idea as it's a reserved word. Use [order] or, better still, a name that doesn't conflict with a reserved word.

This seems to be producing the relevant results, still testing.

the parameters can never be null, just the table records will sometimes be null

Try this:
DECLARE @degID char(5) = ...
DECLARE @progID char(5) = ...
DECLARE @sesID char(4) = ...

WITH matches AS
    SELECT semcode, degreeID, programID, sessionID
        , row_number() OVER (CASE WHEN degreeID IS NOT NULL THEN 0
                                  WHEN programID IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                                  WHEN sessioNID IS NOT NULL THEN 2 END) rn                         
    FROM sems
    WHERE @degID = coalesce(degreeID, @degID)
        AND @progID = coalesce(programID,@progID)
        AND @sesID = coalesce(sessionID, @sesID)

    UNION 
    SELECT NULL semcode, 3
)
SELECT TOP 1 semcode
FROM matches
ORDER BY rn

If it's possible to have inputs that are also NULL, you may need this:
DECLARE @degID char(5) = ...
DECLARE @progID char(5) = ...
DECLARE @sesID char(4) = ...

WITH matches AS
    SELECT semcode, degreeID, programID, sessionID
        , row_number() OVER (CASE WHEN degreeID IS NOT NULL THEN 0
                                  WHEN programID IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                                  WHEN sessioNID IS NOT NULL THEN 2 END) rn                         
    FROM sems
    WHERE coalesce(@degID,'') = coalesce(degreeID, @degID,'')
        AND coalesce(@progID,'') = coalesce(programID,@progID,'')
        AND coalesce(@sesID,'') = coalesce(sessionID, @sesID,'')

    UNION 
    SELECT NULL semcode, 3
)
SELECT TOP 1 semcode
FROM matches
ORDER BY rn


CASE WHEN degreeID IS NOT NULL THEN 0
WHEN programID IS NOT NULL THEN 1
WHEN sessioNID IS NOT NULL THEN 2 END will never evaluate to 1 or 2, because in all cases where programID or sessionID are not null, degreeId is also not null, and the degreeID test comes first. Reversing the order of the whens would I think work.
